# Rails 3.2, saving serialized hash will not save number_with_delimiter()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

It appears that in Rails 3.2.21, saving a serialized hash fails to save a value that comes from one specifc NumberHelper, `helper.number_with_delimiter`

In a Rails 3.2 app, in model Foo I have:

```
serialize :stuff, Hash
```

In the console:

```
f = Foo.create
f.stuff = { a: "aaaa", b: 1111, c: helper.number_with_delimiter(123456) }
=> {:a=>"aaaa", :b=>1111, :c=>"123,456"} # so far so good
f.save!
f.stuff
=> {:a=>"aaaa", :b=>1111, :c=>123456} # c should be a STRING
```

It DOES work correctly with `helper.number_to_currency()`.

And it works if I set `c: String.new(helper.number_with_delimiter(123456))`.

This is a Rails bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Happens on `Rails 4.2.0` as well; looks more like a rails bug.

Comment: This seems to be fixed in Rails 4.2.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a Rails (ActiveSupport) bug that was eventually fixed in Rails 4.2.1. From the 4.2.1 release notes:

> Fixed a roundtrip problem with AS::SafeBuffer where primitive-like strings will be dumped as primitives

When you use `helper.number_with_delimiter`, the resulting object looks and behaves like a String, but in reality it is an `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`.

```
helper.number_with_delimiter(123456).class # => ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer < String
```

When you use:

```
serialize :stuff, Hash
```

That means behind the scenes Rails is using YAML format to save the data to the database. There was a bug in SafeBuffer that caused SafeBuffers like `"123"` to be mistakenly converted to integers (i.e. `123`) instead of remaining strings when saving and loading to/from YAML.

Again, this is now fixed as of Rails 4.2.1. You can see the fix here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/debe7aedda3665702d1f99a3ffb4a123a6c44e9c